# error in creating executable jar in a Maven Project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, testng

I have created a maven project and writing tests in it using testng. I have also created an executable jar using mvn package command but getting error when executing it. I could not actually figure out the error. Please help me with this.

```
$java -jar apitesting1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/testng/ITestListener
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.testng.ITestListener
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
Could not find the main class: apitesting1.apitesting1.App. Program will exit.
```

This is my main class

```
public class myClass 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {

    }
}
```

This is my pom.xml

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>abc</groupId>
<artifactId>abc</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<build> <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                 <executions> <execution>
                                 <goals>
                                     <goal>test-jar</goal>
                                 </goals>
                              </execution>
                 </executions>

                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                           <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                                <mainClass>abc.abc.myClass</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
          </plugin>
```

I am new to Maven.. and copied some of the contents of pom.xml (specifically) from various places.. Please let me know if there is any redundant data or tag. I however feel that there is.. Please help.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The main class element must contain the name of a class. The name of your class is `apitesting1.apitesting1.App`, not `src/main/java/apitesting1.apitesting1.App.java`.

Comment: The error you now show in your edited question simply shows that you're trying to execute a jar file which doesn't exist.

Comment: sorry for the mess up just created... now see the error plz

Comment: So now, your main class is found, but it relies on TestNG classes, which are not in the classpath. Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html.

Comment: I read that link ... got ur point .. but i am not able to get what is missing... I read this **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317147/error-when-creating-an-executable-test-jar-in-maven** post but still, no result.. So, if u could suggest me something... and could you please verify the data in <mainClass> I have my test cases written in AppTest.java . Also do i need to refer to class file or source file ? I am just ready to try anything...:)

Comment: What does your manifest file contain? Have you checked that the classpath of the manifest contains all the required jar files? Have you checked that all these jar files are indeed at the location, relative to the executable jar file, specified in the manifest classpath?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63666/discussion-between-user3436838-and-jb-nizet).

Comment: If you have to ask what the manifest file is, then you haven't read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html with attention. All it talks about is what the manifest file of an executable jar must contain. The manifest file is the file META-INF/MANIFEST.MF that is inside the jar file, and which precisely tells which class is the main class, and what the classpath is.